# Does CombineLatest conserve the order of the observables?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm interested in the following overloads:

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> CombineLatest<TSource>(this params IObservable<TSource>[] sources);
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> CombineLatest<TSource>(this IEnumerable<IObservable<TSource>> sources);
```

Is the order of the elements in the resulting list guaranteed to be the same as the order in the input?

For example, in the following code will `list[0]` always contain an element from `a` and `list[1]` an element from `b`?

```
IObservable<int> a = ...;
IObservable<int> b = ...;
var list = await Observable.CombineLatest(a, b).FirstAsync();
```

The documentations states:

> a list with the latest source elements

and:

> observable sequence containing lists of the latest elements of the sources

but does not really mention anything about order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is conserved.

When you look in the [source code of RX](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET), it all boils down to the `System.Reactive.Linq.CombineLatest<TSource, TResult>` class.

You can find there that an indexed observer is created for each input observable (where the index is the order in the input):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    var j = i;

    var d = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();
    _subscriptions[j] = d;

    var o = new O(this, j);
    d.Disposable = srcs[j].SubscribeSafe(o);
}
```

And the resulting element is produced as follows:

```
private void OnNext(int index, TSource value)
{
    lock (_gate)
    {
        _values[index] = value;
        _hasValue[index] = true;

        if (_hasValueAll || (_hasValueAll = _hasValue.All(Stubs<bool>.I)))
        {
                /* snip */
                res = _parent._resultSelector(new ReadOnlyCollection<TSource>(_values));
                /* snip */

            _observer.OnNext(res);
        }
        /* snip */
    }
}
```

The `_resultSelector` for the overloads I'm interested in is just a `Enumerable.ToList()`. So the order in the output list will be the same as the order in the input.

Answer (score 0):

`CombineLatest` first fires when there was an element pushed to all the streams.

After that it fires whenever a new element is pushed to any of the streams.

So if you "combine" two streams, the resulting list always has two elements in it, and as far as I know it's guaranteed that the order is the same as the order you gave the streams in the `CombineLatest` parameters.

You can visualize Rx operators using marble diagrams. [HERE](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) is the one for `CombineLatest`.

Comment: Do you have any proof that the order is indeed guaranteed? Like a piece of documentation or source code? My initial tests show that the order is indeed conserved, but that's hardly conclusive.

Comment: What would be the point of the whole operator if you don't know which stream is which in the resulting list?

Comment: If you say "as far as I know" then you're not answering the question. You need to be sure about it.

Comment: For that, I can recommend the source code, again as "I can see" (sorry but won't state anything for a 100%), it can't get out of order: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/CombineLatest.cs